# Url of last order of current user

Tags: magento2, orders, url, user

I need to implement a link which redirects to the url of the last order of the current user

How do I do that ?

I have a code that load the last order, but I need to get the URL

```
        $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orders->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
        $orders->addOrder('customer_id');
        $orderId = $orders->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id');
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```

Comment: Do you want this for logged in customers?

Comment: Yes, for the current logged user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
$orders->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
$orders->addOrder('customer_id');
$orderId = $orders->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id');
$url = $block->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $orderId]);
```

And use this in phtml like below:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">View Last Order</a>
```

Comment: Is this going to work with ease logged in user ?

Comment: This will only work for logged in users. Because how do you get customer id without logged in? Does you code returns the last order of that customer?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not clear. Is this going to work if I'm using another user (last order of user 1 : 123, last user of user 2 : 97). If i'm with user 2, will I get the ID 97 ?

Comment: Check mu updated answer. This will return exactly what you need. You only need to replace the your-customer-id with your current customer id.

Comment: With your updated answer, there no order_id (but there was one before you changed your answer)

Comment: No need to get the order id. In the answer i am getting the order then $order->getEntityId() will return the order id.

Comment: This is the result : http://www.portailclient-dev.com/sales/order/view/ (I have 404 error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84183/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-morgan-tartreau).

Comment: Check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order url as given below.

```
$this->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
```